# How to use uniq-c on sorted file

Tags: shell, unix, posix, uniq

I have got sorted file that looks like this: 

`2019 02 09 07 00
2019 02 09 07 00
2019 02 09 08 00
2019 02 09 08 00
2019 02 09 08 00
2019 02 09 08 00
2019 02 09 08 00`

However, when I run `uniq -c` over that file, it doesn't count occurrences as one would expect:

`1 2019 02 09 07 00
1 2019 02 09 07 00
1 2019 02 09 08 00
1 2019 02 09 08 00
1 2019 02 09 08 00
1 2019 02 09 08 00
1 2019 02 09 08 00`

The desired output should look like this:

`2 2019 02 09 07 00
5 2019 02 09 08 00`

I am looking for portable, POSIX compliant solution in shell. Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. I get the expected 2 lines from that input.

Comment: I'm guessing that in your actual input there's some bytes that aren't displaying as characters, or extra whitespace at the end of lines, or something like that to make each line unique. Check a hex dump of the file to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have found the solution. I was processing the file by line and indeed uniq was working with only the line and not the file as a whole.